# Memory Exhaustion from a Deny in CakePHP ACL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

Running CakePHP 2.2 and have a group that has a deny on controllers, and then an allow on several other controllers. If I am logged in as a user of that group and attempt accessing a controller I do not have explicit rights to then I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32 bytes) in
>   /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php on line 672

And also:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 80 bytes) in
>   /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php on line 155

This only occurs when the user does not have access to the controller. Any ideas why this occurs? AppController is configured as:

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'),
        ),
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password'
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => '/users/dashboard', //'/admin/customers/index',//'/admin/tread_designs', // '/shopfloor/build/app.html',
        'logoutRedirect' => '/users/login', //'/shopfloor/build/app.html'
    )
);
```

And beforeFilter:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if($this->RequestHandler->responseType() == 'json'){
        $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json' );
    }

    $this->Auth->ajaxLogin = '/users/session_expired';
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
}
```

Confused on this one and your help is appreciated. Also if I crank memory limit up 1024MB it just times out instead. Something goofy is up.

**UPDATE**
When I tail -f the mysql query log I can see requests that generate this error trying the same 3 queries over and over again.

Comment: I bet on a redirect loop somehow related to the ajax stuff.

Comment: No, there is no ajax redirect loop. I can see the request sit in pending until the memory exhaustion error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Needed to set 'unauthorizedRedirect' => false in AppController

Example:

```
    public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'),
        ),
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password'
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => '/users/dashboard', 
        'logoutRedirect' => '/users/login', 
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false 
    ));
```